# is possible to write css content inside the div

Tags: html, css, css-counter

This is my css for creating counters:

```
#lctndrp li:before{
   content: counters(item, ".") " ";
   counter-increment: item;
}
```

This is my html:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    ::before 
    one
    <ol>
      <li>
        ::before
        one.one
      </li>
      <li>
        ::before
        one.two
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    ::before
    two
    <ol>
      <li>
        ::before
        two.one
      </li>
      <li>
        ::before
        two.two
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

My expected html is:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div>1</div>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div>1.1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>1.2</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>2</div>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div>2.1</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>2.2</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

i have created a counter using css to make this counters 1,1.1,1.2 within the li:before.
I wanted to create a counter within the div tag likewise.Is it possible to solve this problem.If it is possible help me to solve this problem.

Comment: No, that's not how CSS counters work

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML without any CSS already looks like this:

[image: HTML without CSS]

When you add your CSS you get this:

[image: HTML + CSS]

So your counter is displayed!

You can use `list-style-type: none;` to get rid
of the default counter.